# popToRootViewControllerAnimated with UIImagePickerController display Retake button instead of Shoot button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to achieve an application that allows to shoot a photo and display some informations.

When starting the application `UIImagePickerController` is displayed immediatly.
Once photo is taken and the user has clicked "*use*" on the preview screen, I display a first view. In background I contact a server and when I get the response, I display the result view.

My problem is when I try to come back to the `UIImagePickerController`.
The back button invokes `"popToRootViewControllerAnimated"`, getting back to the `UIImagePickerController` : the camera is running but instead of displaying shoot button, I see preview buttons !

How can I reset `UIImagePickerController` ? do I need to allocate a new one ?

Thanks and regards

William

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply dealloc in viewWillDisappear:, then in your viewWillAppear: create a new instance to your liking.

Comment: I don't know where to implement both methods. My main controller is the UIIMagePickerController, so I can't dealloc it from itself. Do I need to create My own UINavigationController with a first "empty" controller which will instanciate the UIImagePickerController in its viewWillAppear method ? Seems a bit complicated ...

Comment: Finally, I created an empty view and implement viewWillAppear method to instanciate the UIImagePicker. The UIImagePicker's delegate is my EmptyViewController and I deallocate the picker from didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method. Thanks BigE.